# Large memory consumption with Ridge

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I'm trying to do cross-validation with scikit-learn, and I'm running into some memory issues that are hard to figure out.

Basically, I've found that when I increase the number of hyperparameters searched, or when I increase the number of cross-validation loops for a GridSearchCV object, I get a nearly linear increase in memory consumption. This makes for dangerously high memory consumption if I use large enough matrices.

Here's a little gist of what I'm talking about:
http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/choldgraf/6a7be7866f2a3a3d3f98

Does anyone know why this might be happening? It seems that GridSearchCV is basically just looping through the cv object and the model parameter options in a list comprehension-style. It doesn't seem like that should increase memory usage...

UPDATE: After looking into this a bit more, it turns out that the problem isn't with GridSearchCV, but rather with a few of the solvers in Ridge (I have updated the gist accordingly). It may be a problem with the scipy linear algebra libraries, see issue [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/4073)

Comment: Take my comment with a (big) grain of salt as I have nothing to back this up it's just something I vaguely recall. Every time sklearn learns a model it copies the learning sets locally for each model to do the learning part. I think it's a trade off between memory consumption and time performances. In that case I think it doesn't just loop between the parameters : it seeds every parameter to a new model at the same time (maybe for multi-threading purposes?)

Comment: Your Gist isn't using `GridSearchCV` at all. @AdrienNK datasets are sometimes copied, but most scikit-learn code does try to avoid copies when it can.

Comment: @larsmans I had a case where I needed to learn from a set of ~2Gb and it loaded 4Gb (peak) in memory (the size of the array in memory + a copy for the model).

Comment: @AdrienNK Yes, but that doesn't happen "every time" as you claimed earlier. 0.15 has been optimized to do much less copying than older versions.

Comment: @larsmans Oh yeah, my bad, I didn't realize I was that categorical there.